# Can we swap integral and limit?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, probability-theory, density-function

$$
D_{\alpha}(p \| q)=\frac{\int ( \alpha p(x)+(1-\alpha) q(x)-[p(x)]^{\alpha}[q(x)]^{1-\alpha}) d x}{\alpha(1-\alpha)},\;\alpha\in(0;1).$$
Here $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are probability densities functions.
It's easy to calculate using L’Hospital’s rule that $\lim\limits_{\alpha\to 0} D_{\alpha}(p \| q) = KL(q||p)$. $KL(q||p)$ is Kullback–Leibler divergence.
But my question is can we swap integral and limit? I solved this task when this operation(swapping) is allowed. I tried to apply Levy's theorem but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Sometimes we can swap, sometimes not.  That is why measure theory takes time to do several theorems: monotone convergence; dominated convergence; and so on.

Comment: @GEdgar I mean in my task. Can we swap or not? I swapped and obtain good result. But I don't know is it legally or not.

Comment: Is the integrand always non-negative ? If so you can apply DCT pretty straightforwardly

Comment: @StratosFair yes, it's non-negative. But what is the function g that dominates the integrand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the integrand is non-negative, you have that for all $\alpha\in[0,1]$ and $x\in \mathbb R$
\begin{align}
 \left|\alpha p(x)+(1-\alpha) q(x)-[p(x)]^{\alpha}[q(x)]^{1-\alpha}\right| &=\alpha p(x)+(1-\alpha) q(x)-[p(x)]^{\alpha}[q(x)]^{1-\alpha}\\
&\le \alpha p(x)+(1-\alpha) q(x)\tag1\\
&=\alpha(p(x)- q(x)) + q(x)\\
&\le \max\{p(x),q(x)\}\tag2
\end{align}
Where $(1)$ is a consequence of the non-negativity of $p(x)^\alpha q(x)^{1-\alpha}$.

As for inequality $(2)$, it follows from observing that the map $\varphi:\alpha\mapsto \alpha(p(x)- q(x)) + q(x)$ is monotone and thus reaches its extremal values at the endpoints of $[0,1]$.

We thus conclude that the family of functions $(f_\alpha)_{0<\alpha<1}$ defined by
$$f_\alpha :x\in\mathbb R\mapsto \alpha p(x)+(1-\alpha) q(x)-[p(x)]^{\alpha}[q(x)]^{1-\alpha}$$
Is dominated by an integrable function and the dominated convergence theorem then allows us to swap integral and limit, as desired.